# CSS How to make wrapper element contain 2 elements it's size, 1 offscreen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

Lets say I want to have a wrapper element which displays one element which is same width height, but on click it slides to the div next to it, which was offscreen before...
Let me draw this real quick:

[Drawing level 9000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLnSD.png)

So clicking on the right arrow would slide /scroll to the offscreen element.

This is mainly for my modals, which look like this:

```
<section class="modal--wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    /* picture i drew goes here */
  </div>
</section>
```

modal--wrapper is fullscreen width / height 100%, position: fixed, while modal is centered, with max-width being 384px (for mobile purposes)

I know how to write logic for this, using getBoundingClientRect, I just don't know how to make the second element offscreen.

```
<section class="user">
  <section class="user__account">/* ... */</section>

  <section class="user__settings">/* ... */</section>
</section>
```

Where user account would be the stuff I drew, while user settings would be the element offscreen.

I tried setting the "user" class display: flex and overflow: hidden, but the two windows just appear one next to each other, both fully visible. Even if I set account and settings width to 384px (the width of the wrapper), they both appear one next to each other. flex-basis 100% on em doesn't work either. Dunno if position absolute would be helpful and I imagine it would require some hacking doing it like that. If thats the way to go I'm down. Just need a lil help where to start. I tried to position em like this but it just doesn't want to work :\

I used to build stuff like this but for elements that scroll up and down, not left and right...

Comment: Usually you would put the inner content in a wrapper and then position that absolute

Comment: Position the wrapper absolute, or the 2 elements absolute, one being left / right 100%?

Comment: the wrapper, then if you want to go up and down you can animate the top and bottom of the wrapper